# Django telegram bot reply keyboard not working

Tags: django, bots, telegram

i have a problem. I've just installed Django with django-telegram-bot [package](https://github.com/JungDev/django-telegrambot)
and I use a function from examples and it basically return a message to user. What I want is to send a reply_keyboard to him. It's strange, but its not working. Here is my code:

```
from telegram.ext import CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters
from telegram import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardMarkup, 
InlineKeyboardButton
from django_telegrambot.apps import DjangoTelegramBot

def me(bot, update):
    keyboard = [
    [
        InlineKeyboardButton("Option 1", callback_data='1'),
        InlineKeyboardButton("Option 2", callback_data='2')
    ],
    [   InlineKeyboardButton("Option 3", callback_data='3')
    ]
    ]

    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)

    # THIS IS PRINTING  TEXT BUT Not keyboard!
    update.message.reply_text('Please choose:', 
    reply_markup=reply_markup)

    # Again sent text
    bot.sendMessage(update.message.chat_id, text='text works' ,reply_markup=markup)
```

I stuck already for 3 days with this problem.

Comment: it seems that you have mistaken in `bot.sendMessage` line: `reply_markup=markup`  - there is no initialized `markup `variable`

Answer (score 0):

this works for me

```
def echo(bot, update):
    keyboard = [
        [
            InlineKeyboardButton("Option 1", callback_data='1'),
            InlineKeyboardButton("Option 2", callback_data='2')
        ],
        [InlineKeyboardButton("Option 3", callback_data='3')
         ]
    ]
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
    bot.sendMessage(update.message.chat_id, text=update.message.text,reply_markup=reply_markup)
```

It seems you have mistaken in `reply_markup=markup` part.

Comment: Thank you for that, but I believe this is not a fix of explained problem.

Comment: @DmitryYudin Hi, why? I have tested this code and it displays a user_keyboard, Can you tell me what is wrong in your code?